# Problem when web scraping dynamically loaded page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using python and selenium to scrape a webpage so I can get all data from some shoes. This is the page:
https://theline.cl/categoria/zapatillas?page=15

This is my code (it includes some things I've tried and haven't worked):

```
def theline_scraper():
    count = 0
    page = 1
    response = {}
    
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36'
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
    options.add_argument('start-maximized') # 
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
    START = 0
    count = 0
    response = {}
    driver.get("https://theline.cl/categoria/zapatillas?page={page}")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# Espera un momento para que la página se actualice
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    #elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mh-product-info')))
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    zapatillas = []
    for product in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "products__item"}):
        name = product.find("h3", {"class": "card-product__title"}).text.strip()
        price = product.find("span", {"class": "price--normal"}).text.strip()
        link = product.find('a')['href']
        zapatilla = {"name": name, "price": price, "link": link}
        zapatillas.append(zapatilla)

    driver.quit()

    print(zapatillas)
    # for i in range(2):
    #     THE_LINE_LINK = "https://theline.cl/categoria/zapatillas?page={page}"
    #     while(True):
    #         # try:
    #         driver.get(THE_LINE_LINK)
    #         html = driver.page_source
    #         soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    #         wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mh-product-info')))
    #         print(wait.text)
    #         break
    #         # except:
    #         #     continue
            
    #     html = driver.page_source
        
    #     # Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML source code
    #     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    #     products = soup.find_all(class_='card-product')
    #     print(products)
    #     page += 1
    #     break
    return response


And in the image is the visualized html I get as a response every time.
```

I've tried different methods of scraping, including the usage of requests library and some waiting methods as well.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. **What exactly is your issue or question?** Also, take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can scrape all the data from multiple pages.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36'
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
options.add_argument('start-maximized')  #
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = Chrome(options=options)


def data_parsing(page_html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    zapatillas = []
    for product in soup.select('div.products__item.col-6.col-md-3'):

        info = product.find('div', {"class": "card-product__info"})

        zapatillas.append({
            "link": product.find('a').get('href'),
            "image": product.find('img').get('src'),
            "brand_name": info.select_one('header>p').text,
            "product_name": info.select_one('header>h3').text,
            "price": product.find('span', {"class": "price"}).text
        })

    return zapatillas


def theline_scraper(pages_to_scrap):
    response = []
    for page in range(1, pages_to_scrap+1):
        driver.get(f"https://theline.cl/categoria/zapatillas?page={page}")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.category__products.products")))

        time.sleep(5)
        page_data = data_parsing(driver.page_source)
        response.extend(page_data)
        print(f"products on page {page}: {len(page_data)}")

    return response

# scrape starting 2 pages
print(theline_scraper(pages_to_scrap=2))
```

output:

```
products on page 1: 48
products on page 2: 48
[{'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-mid-07/CW2289-111', 'image': '/img/products/CW2289-111-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 MID 07', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jordan-stay-loyal-2/DQ8401-016', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8401-016-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'Jordan Stay Loyal 2', 'price': '$132.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-multix-ninos/ADI-FX6400', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FX6400-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS MULTIX NIÑOS', 'price': '$44.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-af1-plt-af-orm/DJ9946-100', 'image': '/img/products/DJ9946-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AF1 PLT AF ORM', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/puma-rs-x-t3ch-rize-morado/387301-02', 'image': '/img/products/387301-02-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'PUMA', 'product_name': 'PUMA RS-X T3CH RIZE MORADO', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-1-mid-na23/DQ8426-060', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8426-060-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 1 MID NA23', 'price': '$142.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-superstar-ninos/ADI-FU7712', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FU7712-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS SUPERSTAR NIÑOS', 'price': '$64.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/rs-x-split-hss/385755-01', 'image': '/img/products/385755-01-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'PUMA', 'product_name': 'RS-X SPLIT HSS', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-mid-gs/DH2933-111', 'image': '/img/products/DH2933-111-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 MID GS', 'price': '$109.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/chuck-taylor-all-star-lift-canvas-negro-ntl/560845C-000', 'image': '/img/products/560845C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'CHUCK TAYLOR ALL STAR LIFT CANVAS NEGRO NTL', 'price': '$64.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jordan-stay-loyal-2/DQ8401-100', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8401-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'Jordan Stay Loyal 2', 'price': '$132.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-plus-se/DQ3981-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ3981-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX PLUS SE', 'price': '$192.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-plus-na23/DM0032-005', 'image': '/img/products/DM0032-005-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX PLUS NA23', 'price': '$194.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/td-old-skool-v-ntl/VN000D3Y-BLK', 'image': '/img/products/VN000D3Y-BLK-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'TD Old Skool V NTL', 'price': '$44.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-force-1-07/DQ7569-100', 'image': '/img/products/DQ7569-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'Nike Air Force 1 07', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-max-270/AH8050-002', 'image': '/img/products/AH8050-002-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MAX 270', 'price': '$129.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-blazer-mid-77-ess/DQ7574-100', 'image': '/img/products/DQ7574-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W BLAZER MID 77 ESS', 'price': '$109.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-force-1-07-ess-trnd-na23/DQ7569-101', 'image': '/img/products/DQ7569-101-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AIR FORCE 1 07 ESS TRND NA23', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatillas-converse-chuck-taylor-all-star-lift/561675C-000', 'image': '/img/products/561675C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'Zapatillas Converse Chuck Taylor All Star Lift', 'price': '$74.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-max-90/DQ4071-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ4071-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MAX 90', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-mid-07/DV0806-001', 'image': '/img/products/DV0806-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 MID 07', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-more-uptempo-td/DQ6202-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ6202-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MORE UPTEMPO TD', 'price': '$79.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-legacy-312-low-gs-na23/CD9054-105', 'image': '/img/products/CD9054-105-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN LEGACY 312 LOW GS NA23', 'price': '$124.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-force-1-07-next-nature/DC9486-101', 'image': '/img/products/DC9486-101-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AIR FORCE 1 07 NEXT NATURE', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-1-mid/DQ8426-014', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8426-014-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 1 MID', 'price': '$142.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-nike-dunk-low-na23/FD1449-100', 'image': '/img/products/FD1449-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W NIKE DUNK LOW NA23', 'price': '$112.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-max-90-ntl/DH8010-100', 'image': '/img/products/DH8010-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR MAX 90 NTL', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-force-1-07/CW2288-111', 'image': '/img/products/CW2288-111-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR FORCE 1 07', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-jordan-3-retro/CK9246-067', 'image': '/img/products/CK9246-067-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO', 'price': '$224.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-force-1-07-se-na23/DV7584-001', 'image': '/img/products/DV7584-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR FORCE 1 07 SE NA23', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-1-low-se/DQ8422-300', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8422-300-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'Air Jordan 1 Low SE', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-more-uptempo-ps/DQ6201-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ6201-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MORE UPTEMPO PS', 'price': '$109.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-07-lv8/DV0794-100', 'image': '/img/products/DV0794-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jordan-stay-loyal-2/DQ8401-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8401-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'JORDAN STAY LOYAL 2', 'price': '$132.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-force-1-07/DD8959-002', 'image': '/img/products/DD8959-002-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR FORCE 1 07', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-dub-zero/311046-162', 'image': '/img/products/311046-162-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN DUB ZERO', 'price': '$164.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jumpman-two-trey-ntl/DO1925-102', 'image': '/img/products/DO1925-102-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'JUMPMAN TWO TREY NTL', 'price': '$174.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-force-1-07/DD8959-103', 'image': '/img/products/DD8959-103-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR FORCE 1 07', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-plus-se-ntl/DQ8960-100', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8960-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX PLUS SE NTL', 'price': '$192.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-07-lv8/DV0789-100', 'image': '/img/products/DV0789-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-90-se/DV1734-100', 'image': '/img/products/DV1734-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX 90 SE', 'price': '$146.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-90-se/DX3576-001', 'image': '/img/products/DX3576-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX 90 SE', 'price': '$146.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-max-90/DQ4071-004', 'image': '/img/products/DQ4071-004-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MAX 90', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/run-star-hike-platform-hi-canvas-negro-ntl/166800C-000', 'image': '/img/products/166800C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'RUN STAR HIKE PLATFORM HI CANVAS NEGRO NTL', 'price': '$76.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/chuck-taylor-all-star-lift-leather-negro-ntl/561681C-000', 'image': '/img/products/561681C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'CHUCK TAYLOR ALL STAR LIFT LEATHER NEGRO NTL', 'price': '$72.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-max-plus-ntl/604133-132', 'image': '/img/products/604133-132-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MAX PLUS NTL', 'price': '$176.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-07-lv8/DV0794-001', 'image': '/img/products/DV0794-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-dunk-hi-retro/DD1399-700', 'image': '/img/products/DD1399-700-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE DUNK HI RETRO', 'price': '$132.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/chuck-taylor-all-star-lift-leather/561680C-000', 'image': '/img/products/561680C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'CHUCK TAYLOR ALL STAR LIFT LEATHER', 'price': '$72.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-af1-shadow/DZ5193-100', 'image': '/img/products/DZ5193-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AF1 SHADOW', 'price': '$146.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-3-retro-na23/DN3707-100', 'image': '/img/products/DN3707-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO NA23', 'price': '$226.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-max-270/AH6789-110', 'image': '/img/products/AH6789-110-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AIR MAX 270', 'price': '$129.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-dunk-hi-retro/DD1399-401', 'image': '/img/products/DD1399-401-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE DUNK HI RETRO', 'price': '$132.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/forum-bold-w/ADI-FY9042', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FY9042-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'FORUM BOLD W', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-max-90-ntl/DH8010-002', 'image': '/img/products/DH8010-002-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR MAX 90 NTL', 'price': '$139.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/ua-sk8-low/VN0A4UUK-6BT', 'image': '/img/products/VN0A4UUK-6BT-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'UA SK8-LOW', 'price': '$64.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/wmns-air-jordan-1-low-na23/DC0774-501', 'image': '/img/products/DC0774-501-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'WMNS AIR JORDAN 1 LOW NA23', 'price': '$126.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-95/DQ9016-001', 'image': '/img/products/DQ9016-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX 95', 'price': '$192.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-5-retro-se/DV1310-401', 'image': '/img/products/DV1310-401-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 5 RETRO SE', 'price': '$242.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/forum-low/ADI-FY7757', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FY7757-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'FORUM LOW', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/run-star-motion-hi-negra-nna/171545C-000', 'image': '/img/products/171545C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'RUN STAR MOTION HI NEGRA NNA', 'price': '$89.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-more-uptempo-96/FB1380-100', 'image': '/img/products/FB1380-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MORE UPTEMPO 96', 'price': '$176.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-superstar-hombres/ADI-EG4958', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-EG4958-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS SUPERSTAR HOMBRES', 'price': '$84.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-97-fr/DQ8961-100', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8961-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX 97 FR', 'price': '$199.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-max-terrascape-90/DM0033-003', 'image': '/img/products/DM0033-003-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MAX TERRASCAPE 90', 'price': '$156.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-forum-low-hombre/ADI-IG7596', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-IG7596-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS FORUM LOW HOMBRE', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/ua-old-skool/VN000D3H-BKA', 'image': '/img/products/VN000D3H-BKA-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'UA OLD SKOOL', 'price': '$64.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-force-1-high-07-lv8/DV0790-200', 'image': '/img/products/DV0790-200-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR FORCE 1 HIGH 07 LV8', 'price': '$154.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/run-star-hike-platform-blanco-ntl/166799C-000', 'image': '/img/products/166799C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'RUN STAR HIKE PLATFORM BLANCO NTL', 'price': '$76.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/converse-run-star-hike-platform-ox-canvas-negro-ntl/168816C-000', 'image': '/img/products/168816C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'CONVERSE RUN STAR HIKE PLATFORM OX CANVAS NEGRO NTL', 'price': '$74.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/forum-low/ADI-FY7755', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FY7755-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'FORUM LOW', 'price': '$99.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/superstar-cf-i/ADI-HQ4286', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-HQ4286-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'SUPERSTAR CF I', 'price': '$52.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-nike-af1-shadow/DR7883-101', 'image': '/img/products/DR7883-101-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W NIKE AF1 SHADOW', 'price': '$146.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-11-retro/CT8012-116', 'image': '/img/products/CT8012-116-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 11 RETRO', 'price': '$226.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-sb-chron-2-canvas-skate-shoe/DM3494-002', 'image': '/img/products/DM3494-002-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE SB CHRON 2 CANVAS SKATE SHOE', 'price': '$66.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-max-90/DX0115-100', 'image': '/img/products/DX0115-100-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AIR MAX 90', 'price': '$144.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jordan-series-mid/DA8026-004', 'image': '/img/products/DA8026-004-2_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'JORDAN SERIES MID', 'price': '$106.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-1-mid-se/DQ8417-006', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8417-006-2_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'Air Jordan 1 Mid SE', 'price': '$146.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/old-skool-stacked-checkerboard/VN0A4U15VLV-U32', 'image': '/img/products/VN0A4U15VLV-U32-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'OLD SKOOL STACKED (CHECKERBOARD)', 'price': '$79.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/jordan-zion-2/DV0549-164', 'image': '/img/products/DV0549-164-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'JORDAN ZION 2', 'price': '$134.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/chuck-taylor-all-star-lift-hi-canvas-wms/560846C-000', 'image': '/img/products/560846C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'CHUCK TAYLOR ALL STAR LIFT HI CANVAS WMS', 'price': '$64.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-multix-ninos/ADI-FX6231', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-FX6231-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS MULTIX NIÑOS', 'price': '$52.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/mundo-skate-uy-old-skool-v-gs/VN000VHE-ENR', 'image': '/img/products/VN000VHE-ENR-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'Mundo Skate UY OLD SKOOL V GS', 'price': '$49.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-1-hi-flyease/CQ3835-061', 'image': '/img/products/CQ3835-061-2_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN 1 HI FLYEASE', 'price': '$149.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/run-star-motion/172895C-000', 'image': '/img/products/172895C-000-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'CONVERSE', 'product_name': 'RUN STAR MOTION', 'price': '$87.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-max-270/AH8050-199', 'image': '/img/products/AH8050-199-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'AIR MAX 270', 'price': '$129.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-forum-hombres/ADI-GX4121', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-GX4121-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS FORUM HOMBRES', 'price': '$94.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/slipstream-lth/387544-03', 'image': '/img/products/387544-03-5_640.png', 'brand_name': 'PUMA', 'product_name': 'SLIPSTREAM LTH', 'price': '$84.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/zapatilla-adidas-forum-mujer/ADI-GY9517', 'image': '/img/products/ADI-GY9517-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'ADIDAS', 'product_name': 'ZAPATILLA ADIDAS FORUM MUJER', 'price': '$109.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/air-jordan-legacy-312-low/CD7069-105', 'image': '/img/products/CD7069-105-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'AIR JORDAN LEGACY 312 LOW', 'price': '$162.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-jordan-1-elevate-low-se/DQ8394-301', 'image': '/img/products/DQ8394-301-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'JORDAN', 'product_name': 'W AIR JORDAN 1 ELEVATE LOW SE', 'price': '$159.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-af1-plt-af-orm-lv8-na23/FD0382-121', 'image': '/img/products/FD0382-121-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AF1 PLT AF ORM LV8 NA23', 'price': '$144.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/ca-pro-classic-ps/382278-01', 'image': '/img/products/382278-01-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'PUMA', 'product_name': 'CA PRO CLASSIC PS', 'price': '$44.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/nike-air-more-uptempo-kc-bp-ntl/FB1343-001', 'image': '/img/products/FB1343-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'NIKE AIR MORE UPTEMPO KC BP NTL', 'price': '$106.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/ua-sk8-hi-ntl/VN000D5I-B8C', 'image': '/img/products/VN000D5I-B8C-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'VANS', 'product_name': 'UA SK8-HI NTL', 'price': '$72.990'}, {'link': 'https://theline.cl/w-air-max-270/AH6789-001', 'image': '/img/products/AH6789-001-1_640.png', 'brand_name': 'NIKE', 'product_name': 'W AIR MAX 270', 'price': '$129.990'}]
```